# Which translation is better Philippians 4:6 Pray about everything (NLT) or pray in every situation?

Tags: greek, philippians, prayer

NLT "Pray about everything" implies ask for anything, don't hesitate in asking even for little things, ask everything freely; be meticulous. Whereas other translations put it "in everything or in any situation.. pray". There is a difference between praying under every situation and praying for anythings that we need. What is your analysis? [Philippians 4:6 translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/philippians%204:6)

> Don’t worry about anything; instead, pray about everything. Tell God
>   what you need, and thank him for all he has done. (NLT)
>
> Do not be anxious about anything. Instead, in every situation,
>   through prayer and petition with thanksgiving, tell your requests to
>   God. (NET)
>
> do not be anxious about anything, but in everything by prayer and
>   supplication with thanksgiving let your requests be made known to God.
>   (ESV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek says literally "in everything by prayer and by supplication with thanksgiving your requests let be made known to God" (εν παντι τη προσευχη και τη δεησει μετα ευχαριστιας τα αιτηματα υμων γνωριζεσθω προς τον Θεον).

Consider this alternate translation from *The Orthodox New Testament*, which is fairly literal:

> *Cease being anxious about anything, but in everything by prayer and entreaty, with giving of thanks, let your requests be made known to
>   God*

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! Thank you for your contribution. Please also consider taking the site [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour). We hope you continue to participate here.